# Best way to find a closest vector in a lattice

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, na.numerical-analysis, lattices, computational-number-theory

Let $v_1,\dotsc,v_n$ be linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\Lambda=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n \mathbb{Z}v_i$.  The question is, given a vector $w$ in $\mathbb R^n$, find the element $v$ of the lattice $\Lambda$ closest to $w$.  It is assumed that an inner product structure has been imposed on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  This is called the CVP (for closest vector problem).

I've found various algorithms that can find the closest vector, but is there a particular algorithm that is especially simple to understand and to program?  I want to test a few low dimensional examples, and easy to write computer code would be preferable.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi, I've added the algorithms and numerical analysis tags - apologies if you think they're not appropriate.

Comment: http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/damien.stehle/downloads/SVPCVP.pdf

Answer (score 7):

A nice rahter-simple option would be [Babai's Nearest Plane Algorithm](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~odedr/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/cvp.pdf). This is an **approximation** algorithm which outputs a vector of the lattice which is "close" the given target $w$. The accuracy of the approximation depends on the rank $n$ of the lattice. The good things are: the algorithm runs in polynomial-time and it is fairly easy to implement.

> **Input:** Basis $B\in\mathbb{Z}^{m\times n}, w\in\mathbb{Z}^{m}$
>
> **Output:** A vector $x\in \mathcal{L}(B)$ such that $\lVert x - w\rVert \leq 2^{\frac{n}{2}} \:\text{dist}(w,\mathcal{L}(B))$
>
> 1. Run $\delta$-LLL on $B$ with $\delta=3/4$.
> 2. $b \leftarrow w$
>
>    **for** $j = n$ to $1$ **do**
>
>    $\qquad b=b-c_j b_j$ where $c_j = \lceil \langle b, \tilde{b}_j \rangle / \langle \tilde{b}_j, \tilde{b}_j \rangle\rfloor$
>
>    Output $x:=w-b$

Above, $\delta$-LLL denotes the [Lenstra-Lenstra-Lovasz algorithm](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~odedr/goto.php?name=ln_lll&link=teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/lll.pdf), used as a subroutine to obtain a [$\delta$-LLL Reduced Basis](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~odedr/goto.php?name=ln_lll&link=teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/lll.pdf) $\lbrace b_1,\ldots,b_n \rbrace$ of your original basis $\lbrace v_j \rbrace$. The vectors $\lbrace \tilde{b}_j \rbrace$ are the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization of the LLL basis.

It seems that this algorithm is normally the first to be taught in university courses. I read these algorithms and definitions in Oded Regev's course about [Lattices in Computer Science](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~odedr/teaching/lattices_fall_2009/index.html).

For **exacts** algorithms, this [short review](http://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~sgal018/crypto-book/ch19.pdf) might be helpful. Alternatively, [this text](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/guillaume.hanrot/Papers/iwcc.pdf) is more technical but rather complete.